# Unable to pass kwarg into an inlineformset_factory?

Tags: django, view, formset

THere is an answer here that doesnt solve my problem.
[Pass kwarg into an inlineformset_factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366997/pass-kwarg-into-an-inlineformset-factory)

This is my view class, error message inline

```
class InvoiceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Invoice
    fields = (
        'client',
        'order_number',
    )
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
########## ERROR MESSAGE "_init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form_kwargs'"
        kwargs['form_kwargs'] = {'request': self.request}
##########
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(InvoiceCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['track_formset'] = InvoiceFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['track_formset'] = InvoiceFormSet()
        return data

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, username=self.request.user.pk)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.referer = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "")
        request.session["login_referer"] = self.referer
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.referer = request.session.get("login_referer", "")
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        up = UserProfile.objects.get(username=self.request.user.pk)
        form.instance.profile = up
        bk = BankAccount.objects.get(profile=up)
        form.instance.user_bank = bk

        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        formset = context['track_formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            response = super().form_valid(form)
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return response
        else:
            return super().form_invalid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.path
```

This is my form code (no errors here,added for completeness)

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Description', initial='Some info')
    class Meta:
        model=Invoice
        exclude = ["username", "invoice_number", "invoice_status", "profile", 
                   "user_bank", "date_from", "date_to","total",]
        model=LineItem
#        readonly_fields = ['total'] # currency default changes if this is set
        exclude = ["user",]

InvoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Invoice,
    LineItem,
    form=InvoiceForm,
    min_num=1,  # minimum number of forms that must be filled in
    extra=1,  # number of empty forms to display
    can_delete=False
)
```

I followed the documentation here, the examples give me the same error
Using Django==4.1.6
Python 3.9.12
Fedora 37
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be an issue with the `get_object` function,modify it to

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(self.model, user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: he error remains, I was calling user -> usename in the model, it is a bit confusing I know

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't use your form in the view.

Second, you didn't really follow docs you've linked, your form doesn't define `__init__()` method.

Comment: I am calling the form from InvoiceFormSet, see form=InvoiceForm,

Comment: Yes, but view still doesn't use it, so doesn't use it's overridden method

Comment: I ended up sending the user as context, it probably is not the best option but it works for me.